# C# Selenium Extract Data from span with partial ID

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I am trying to create a proper XPATH syntax in C# Selenium to extract an order number on a web page.  Here is what I've tried to far to grab the order number shown in the screen shot.  All of these have errored out on me.

```
var result = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@id^='order-number-'")).Text;
var result = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='a-column a-span7']/h5")).Text;
var result = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='a-column a-span7']/span[@class='a-text-bold']")).Text;
```

Below is the inspection from Chrome.  I am trying to grab the order number, but it will not always be the same so I cannot hard code the span id.

[image]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but have you tried something like this: 

id*='order-number' in your xpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@id^='order-number-'"))` would definitely match nothing since `^=` is not a valid operator in XPath language. Plus, you are not closing the square brackets.

Instead, if you want to have a shorter and more readable version, use a CSS selector:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span[id^=order-number]"))
```

Here `^=` means "starts with".

---

If you want to stay with XPath, use [`starts-with()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/starts-with):

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[starts-with(@id, 'order-number-')]"))
```

Comment: This worked great.  Thank you sir.  var result = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span[id^=order-number]")).Text;

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out:

```
var result = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(@id, 'order-number-')]")).Text;
```

It uses a "contains" on the span ID. Let me know if this helps.